# Google smart home actions for thermostat report state issue

Tags: google-smart-home

I am developing thermostat ReportState functions, I use Smart Home Report State Dashboard to
check the status, It seems report state is OK when I manually set the temperature, I can see the temperature value from dashboard, but I try to use google assistant App to set or ask the temperature, it will return correct status by voice, but In google assistant App UI status no
changes as attached file. Is anything I miss reply to Google’s Home Graph?

Here is the state value I report as below:
{
thermostatMode: 'cool',
thermostatTemperatureSetpoint: 89,
thermostatTemperatureAmbient: 76,
thermostatHumidityAmbient: 61
}

BR,
Jack

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not related to your Report State implementation. That UI panel is populated using your response to the `EXECUTE` intent and the subsequent `QUERY` issued to confirm the state change.

Ensure that you are returning the updated state in the `EXECUTE` response, and verify that the state values you provided via Report State are also present in the `QUERY` response (a `QUERY` response should always contain the full set of current states).